# Can't show template in page

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, template, phtml, page

[image]

this's content of page. but it not show on front-end.

Comment: Please also share events.phtml code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the core/template block has the right permission, from system->permission->blocks and core/template is allowed or not.
If it is allowed then double check the template file path

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have correctly specified the path to the template.
Check the path of events/events.phtml

You can show where in you is this pattern? Interested in a file path as necessary to ensure true test whether the path